# Determine elapsed time between events attended summarized by users in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, summarize

```
EmpId   Terminal    TimeStamp
1   A   2021-11-16 05:00:15
2   B   2021-11-16 05:00:15
1   B   2021-11-16 06:05:00
2   C   2021-11-16 09:00:15
1   A   2021-11-16 08:00:15
2   B   2021-11-16 11:00:15

**DataTable**
let T = datatable(EmpId:string , Terminal:string, TimeStamp:datetime )
[
   "1", "A", datetime(2021-11-16 05:00:15),
   "2", "B", datetime(2021-11-16 05:00:15),
   "1", "B", datetime(2021-11-16 06:05:00),
   "1", "A", datetime(2021-11-16 08:00:15),
   "2", "B", datetime(2021-11-16 11:00:15),
   "2", "C", datetime(2021-11-16 09:00:15),
];
T   
    | order by TimeStamp asc
    | extend elapsedTime = datetime_diff('minute', next(TimeStamp), TimeStamp)
| summarize Travelled=count(), TerminalT = strcat_array(make_list(Terminal), "->"), TimeStamp=strcat_array(make_list(TimeStamp), "->"),  ElapsTime=strcat_array(make_list(elapsedTime), "->") by EmpId
```

Expected result:
EmpId   Terminal    TimeStamp   TimeSpentinMins
1   A->B->A 2021-11-16 05:00:15 - >2021-11-16 06:05:00->2021-11-18 08:00:15 65->115
2   B->C->B 2021-11-16 05:00:15->2021-11-16 09:00:15->2021-11-16 11:00:15   240->120

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpwB8.png)

Not getting the expected result as the serialize/order by clause required is reordering the events.
Need a way to group by employee id and then order by TimeStamp within each group, so that the elapsed time is caluculated as expected. Is it feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see 2 options below. The 2nd should perform better for larger data sets.

**Option #1**

```
let T = datatable(EmpId:string , Terminal:string, TimeStamp:datetime )
[
   "1", "A", datetime(2021-11-16 05:00:15),
   "2", "B", datetime(2021-11-16 05:00:15),
   "1", "B", datetime(2021-11-16 06:05:00),
   "1", "A", datetime(2021-11-16 08:00:15),
   "2", "B", datetime(2021-11-16 11:00:15),
   "2", "C", datetime(2021-11-16 09:00:15),
];
T   
| order by EmpId, TimeStamp asc
| extend elapsedTime = iff(next(EmpId) == EmpId, datetime_diff('minute', next(TimeStamp), TimeStamp), long(null))
| summarize Travelled=count(), 
TerminalT = strcat_array(make_list(Terminal), "->"), 
TimeStamp=strcat_array(make_list(TimeStamp), "->"),  ElapsTime=strcat_array(make_list_if(elapsedTime, elapsedTime != long(null)), "->") by EmpId
```

| EmpId | Travelled | TerminalT | TimeStamp | ElapsTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | B->C->B | 2021-11-16T05:00:15.0000000Z->2021-11-16T09:00:15.0000000Z->2021-11-16T11:00:15.0000000Z | 240->120 |
| 1 | 3 | A->B->A | 2021-11-16T05:00:15.0000000Z->2021-11-16T06:05:00.0000000Z->2021-11-16T08:00:15.0000000Z | 65->115 |

**Option #2**: using the [partition operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator)

```
let T = datatable(EmpId:string , Terminal:string, TimeStamp:datetime )
[
   "1", "A", datetime(2021-11-16 05:00:15),
   "2", "B", datetime(2021-11-16 05:00:15),
   "1", "B", datetime(2021-11-16 06:05:00),
   "1", "A", datetime(2021-11-16 08:00:15),
   "2", "B", datetime(2021-11-16 11:00:15),
   "2", "C", datetime(2021-11-16 09:00:15),
];
T 
| partition hint.strategy=native by EmpId
(
    order by TimeStamp asc
    | extend elapsedTime = datetime_diff('minute', next(TimeStamp), TimeStamp)
    | summarize Travelled=count(), 
    TerminalT = strcat_array(make_list(Terminal), "->"), 
    TimeStamp=strcat_array(make_list(TimeStamp), "->"),  ElapsTime=strcat_array(make_list(elapsedTime), "->") by EmpId
)
```

| EmpId | Travelled | TerminalT | TimeStamp | ElapsTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | A->B->A | 2021-11-16T05:00:15.0000000Z->2021-11-16T06:05:00.0000000Z->2021-11-16T08:00:15.0000000Z | 65->115 |
| 2 | 3 | B->C->B | 2021-11-16T05:00:15.0000000Z->2021-11-16T09:00:15.0000000Z->2021-11-16T11:00:15.0000000Z | 240->120 |